# Spring - Thymeleaf - 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, thymeleaf

I'm worked with Spring in the past on a big project, but I've never started a Spring MVC web app from scratch.

Well that's what I'm currently doing now for practice as I have a project coming up that will require it.

I was successfully able to make a simple Spring MVC Web App that used .JSP pages (using annotations, no XML). 
I wanted to use Thymeleaf though and started my conversion process to that.

Well now I'm getting a 404 Error and my HomeController class isn't even being hit it seems like.

I get no errors in the Console output.

I've Google search, read through tutorials, and code samples. Second pair of eyes would be nice. Thanks! :)

Note: going from .JSP to Thymeleaf the only changes made was the addition of the ThymeleafConfig class. I don't see how it went from working to not working.

Here's my code:

WebInit.java

```
public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Creates the root application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ServletConfig.class);
        appContext.setDisplayName("REPLACE ME");
        appContext.setConfigLocation("com.demo.config");

        // Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

        // Further configures the servlet context
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.setAsyncSupported(true);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

ServetConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(WebConfig.class)
@ImportResource({/*"classpath:META-INF/spring/persistence-context.xml"*/})
public class ServletConfig {

}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.illinois.dnr")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ThymeleafConfig.class})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // Maps resources path to webapp/resources
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/");
    }

    // Provides internationalization of messages
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        return source;
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf.java

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {
    @Bean 
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean 
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean 
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dnr", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Login");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@Validated User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userName", user.getUserName());
        logger.info("User");
        return "user";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        logger.info("Hello");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page - Admin Page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");
        logger.info("admin");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dba**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView dbaPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page - Database Page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");
        logger.info("dba");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using STS and tomcat7

Comment: Is there a stack trace to speak of?  Also, can you put `System.out.println()'s in your `ThymeleafConfig` methods to make sure they are running.  Are all your Thymeleaf templates in WEB-INF/views?

Comment: Remember that you should go to localhost:8080/appName/dnr and page is WEB-INF/views/dnr.html

Comment: CodeChimp: Thanks for the idea of running System.out's in my methods! Should have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps but you can simplified `WebInit` by extends`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` instead of implements `WebApplicationInitializer`. Otherwise Thymeleaf configuration seems ok to me (suppose it's called). I'm giving here working skeleton of config so you can experiment with it.

WebApplicationInitializer

```
public class WebInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.kreuzman")
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCacheTTLMs(0l);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully this helps other people that want a purely Annotation based Spring Web App. I've found several tutorials and help guides, but they all have their own "style" on how they set things up. I finally found a working example of Spring MVC-Security-WebFlow, Hibernate, and Thymeleaf project. There config files are setup similar to your skeleton. Definitely doing this route. Much cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What page are you trying to hit? Does that html page exist in /WEB-INF/views/?

Is it a JSP page? you need to exclude all pages that are not going to be resolved by ThymeleafViewResolver. I also noticed you didn't set the ThymeleafViewResolver to first in the order.

Like so

```
@Bean 
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() 
{
    String[] excludedViews = new String[]{
        "login", "logout"};

    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    /*
     * This is how we get around Thymeleaf view resolvers throwing an error instead of returning
     * of null and allowing the next view resolver in the {@see
     * DispatcherServlet#resolveViewName(String, Map<String, Object>, Locale,
     * HttpServletRequest)} to resolve the view.
     */
    resolver.setExcludedViewNames(excludedViews);
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: I tried setting the setOrder(1) and it didn't work. I ended up deleting the project and starting from scratch again. The only difference this time was I used this dependency : javax 6.0

Comment: You did help me exclude out .JSP pages if i wanted to support both .JSP and .html pages. So thank you for that